# SVM and KNN variable Importance Factor getting error in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have done RF, BRT and CART variable importance factors in GEE, but I faced errors in svm and knn. Here is the code

```
/////RF_importance/////
var rf_dict = classifier.explain();
print('Explain:',rf_dict);
 var rf_variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(rf_dict).get('importance'));
 
var rf_chart =
ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(rf_variable_importance)
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({
title: 'Random Forest Variable Importance',
legend: {position: 'none'},
hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
});
 
print(rf_chart);

/////SVM_importance////
var svm_dict = classifier_svm.explain();
print('Explain:',svm_dict);
 var svm_variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(svm_dict));
 
var svm_chart =
ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(svm_variable_importance)
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({
title: 'Support Vector Machine Variable Importance',
legend: {position: 'none'},
hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
});
 
print(svm_chart);

////KNN_importance////
var knn_dict = classifier_knn.explain();
print('Explain:',knn_dict);
 var knn_variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(knn_dict));
 
var knn_chart =
ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(knn_variable_importance)
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({
title: 'K-Nearest Neighbor Variable Importance',
legend: {position: 'none'},
hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
});
 
print(knn_chart);`
```

Comment: There's no such thing for non-tree classifiers.

Comment: Then how to calculate SVM and KNN variable importance? Any other recommendations?